# Jquery Plugin Sometimes load sometimes not load

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins

Im develop a platform, use mvc + wcf + jquery + ajax ..

I dont have good english so i upload image

[image]

This is Ajax Response

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#{0}').flexigrid({
        url: 'GetDataList/',
        singleSelect: true,
        colModel: [{1}],
        searchitems: [{2}],
        sortorder: 'asc',
        usepager: true,
        title: '{3}',
        rp: 15,
        showTableToggleBtn: true
    });
    alert('{0} isimli grid load oldu');
});
</script>
```

I see alert message correctly but plugin sometimes not load

and not only for Flexigrid all jquery plugins sometimes not load sometimes load..

Edit 1-

I think **can not initialize** jquery requests from ajax

Comment: Any errors in the console when the plugins aren't loading?

Comment: when they don't load, is there any console output? you can see it in chromes developer console, or in firebug.

Comment: I think selector will not be available.

Comment: I would add an alert or console-output directly to the ready-function. If it is executed every time, than the selector should be the problem.

Comment: Amit, maybe you're right. But sometimes, the correct plug-in is running.
How can we make this work correctly.

Comment: Sammy I add alert all functions and executed every time. You are right. But how can i use selector this the structure of this study

Comment: Use this to check the plugin is loaded. if (jQuery().pluginName) { alert('Plugin loaded');}

Answer (score 1):

if I understood you question, this is my approach in order to initialize the flexigrid

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#invitedschoolstable").flexigrid({
                            url: 'index.php?option=com_users&task=profile.getinvitedschools&query='+id+'&format',//getSearchResults()
                            dataType: 'json',
                            colModel : [
                                {display: 'id', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center', hide: true},
                                {display: 'Σχολή', name : 'schoolname', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'left', hide: false},
                                {display: 'Στοιχεία επικοινωνίας', name : 'stoixeiaepik', width : 250, sortable : false, align: 'left', hide: false},
                                {display: 'Κωδ.Σχολ', name : 'schoolid', width : 250, sortable : false, align: 'left', hide: true}
                                ],
                                sortname: "id",
                                sortorder: "asc",
                                usepager: true,
                                title: 'Λίστα προσκεκλημένων σχολών',
                                useRp: true,
                                rp: 10,
                                showTableToggleBtn: true,
                                width: 500,
                                nowrap: false,
                                height: 'auto',                         
                                onSuccess: invitedschoolstableSuccess,
                                qtype:'eventid',
                                query: id
                        }); 
});
```

and this is the php at the back end that is being accessed via ajax
**Notice** that I am using some indoor joomla tricks here in order to request the values that are posted and make a query to the database but there is not much difference. Simply replace those with the php $_REQUEST and the classical mysql command to access the database.
So don't blindly copy paste the code.

```
public function getinvitedschools(){
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();

            $page = 1; // The current page
            $sortname = 'id'; // Sort column
            $sortorder = 'asc'; // Sort order
            $qtype = ''; // Search column
            $query = ''; // Search string
            // Get posted data
                $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;        
                $page = $jinput->get('page','','INT'); 

                //$eventid = $jinput->get('eventid','','INT');

                $sortname = $jinput->get('sortname','','STRING');

                $sortorder = $jinput->get('sortorder','','STRING');

                $qtype = $jinput->get('qtype','','STRING');

                $query = $jinput->get('query','','STRING');

                $rp = $jinput->get('rp');

            // Setup sort and search SQL using posted data
            $sortSql = ($sortname != '' && $sortorder != '') ? " order by $sortname $sortorder" : '';
            if (strpos($query, '%') !== false) {
                $searchSql = ($qtype != '' && $query != '') ? "where $qtype like '$query'" : '';
            }
            else 
            {
                $searchSql = ($qtype != '' && $query != '') ? "where $qtype = '$query'" : '';
            }

            if($searchSql=="")
             $searchSql.=" where d.dhmos=b.id and d.nomos=c.id and d.id=e.schoolid ";
            else
             $searchSql.=" and d.dhmos=b.id and d.nomos=c.id and d.id=e.schoolid  ";

            // Get total count of records
            $sql = "select count(*)
                    FROM #__Greekgeolocations b , 
                        #__Greekgeolocations c, 
                        #__fcse_fightclubs d    , 
                        #__fcse_eventsdiasil_schoollistselection e                  
            $searchSql";

            $db->setQuery($sql);
            $total = $db->loadResult();



            $pageStart = ($page-1)*$rp;
            $limitSql = "limit $pageStart, $rp";        
            $data = array();
            $data['page'] = $page;
            $data['total'] = $total;
            $data['rows'] = array();        
            $sql = "SELECT d.id,
                    b.locname as polhname,                       
                    c.locname as nomosname,         
                    d.address,      
                    d.name,
                    e.responsedate,
                    e.responseid                    
            FROM #__Greekgeolocations b , 
                #__Greekgeolocations c, 
                #__fcse_fightclubs d    , 
                #__fcse_eventsdiasil_schoollistselection e                         
            $searchSql              
            $sortSql
            $limitSql";

            //echo $sql;
            //die();
            $db->setQuery($sql);
            $results = $db->loadObjectList();

            foreach( $results as $row ){

                $today = new DateTime($row->thetimestamp);
                $today = $today->getTimestamp();

                 //$today = new DateTime('2013-03-21 17:30:00');
                 //$today = $today->getTimestamp();


                $data['rows'][] = array(
                        'id' => $row->id,
                        'cell' => array($row->id,                                       
                                        $row->name,
                                        $row->nomosname.' '.$row->polhname.' '.$row->address,
                                        $row->id
                                        ));
            }

            echo json_encode($data);    
    }
```

You can add this code to a jquery ready state or any other event and also you can use qtype and query to pass the first initialization values.

If you need to add code that requires the flexigrid to be **loaded** use the onSuccess: and hook a method to it like invitedschoolstableSuccess which is actually a function defined in your code like function invitedschoolstableSuccess(){} 'name it anything you like' so you can execute your code there.

Also if you need to reload your flexigrid with other options later on you may use the following code within a click event or any other event you wish like this

```
jQuery('#invitedschoolstable').flexOptions({ qtype:'school',query: 32 }).flexReload();
```

You can also assign variables instead of a fixed value like I did "school" and 32.

I hope this helps